# How to declare variable and use it in Oracle sql

Tags: oracle

i want to delcare a variable and use it in the same oracle sql

suppose we have the following script which is working fine

```
select id
,NAME
,ADDRESS
,DATE
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE COMPANY= 'LENOVO'
AND DATEBETWEEN systimestamp - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
AND SYSTIMESTAMP
```

At the end of this code i want to store the value of ID in a variable and then it to delete the record, i tried this but it's not working

```
declare
_name varchar(100);

select id
    ,NAME
    ,ADDRESS
    ,DATE
    FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE COMPANY= 'LENOVO'
    AND DATEBETWEEN systimestamp - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
    AND SYSTIMESTAMP
Returning to _name;

delete _name;
```

Any help please, thank you

Comment: Where are you running the script - SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, some other client? What are you doing with the selected data before deleting, just displaying it?

Comment: I'm just displaying it to get the id and i'M using oracle sql developper 3.0.04

Comment: If you're just displaying it to get the ID, do you actually need to display it (or rather, them, as I assume it can match more that one record with that interval) at all? I'm unclear why you aren't just dong a straight delete with the same `where` clause. The `declare` implies you want to do this in a PL/SQL block, possibly looping around a cursor to display and delete each matching record; is that the case? It's all a bit unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [`SELECT INTO` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm):

```
SELECT id
INTO _name
FROM MYTABLE;
```